# Naming and adding columns to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on combining various text files into one data frame,

So far I have

```
files = list.files()
data = lapply(files,function(x) read.table(x)) 
data_rbind <- do.call("rbind", data)
```

I would like to add column titles, 
I have tried

```
colnames(data_rbind)=c('car','colour','price')
```

However, this gives the error message

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("car", "colour", "price")) :
>   'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

I would then like to add a 4th column entitled 'Year' with the values corresponding to the name of each file. Is this possible?

edit- I have realised the above error is because my dataframe reads as only 1 variable when it should be 3. The 3 columns all appear to be contained within 1 column. i am not sure why this happened.

I would like to separate the data into 3 separate columns and for structure function to read

```
data.frame':    9001 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "Toyota" "BMW" "Ford" ...
 $ V2: chr  "Blue" "Red" "Red" "Silver" ...
 $ V3: int  80412 65443 47920 41560 38019 29618 29074 28885 26159 25693 ...
```

I am working with txt files, each file has a number of rows containing 3 values separated by a comma, 
for example,

> Ford,Red,8041
>
> Toyota,Silver,6544
>
> BMW,Red,4792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that your vector of names is not of the same length as the number of columns in your dataframe.  If you want to set the names of specific columns, do the following

```
#assume car, colour, and price correspond to columns 1, 3, 4
colnames(dataframe)[c(1,3,4)]<-c("car", "colour", "price")
```

if you want to add a column entitled Year, you may add it by

```
df$Year<-values
```

although you will need to make sure that the number of entries in values is equal to the number of rows in df for the desired results.  The name of that column will then be "Year"

just to show that it works, I made a simple txt file based on the question's provided example.  After lapply I get

```
#[[1]]
#      V1     V2   V3
#1   Ford    Red 8041
#2 Toyota Silver 6544
#3    BMW    Red 4792
#
#[[2]]
#      V1     V2   V3
#1   Ford    Red 8041
#2 Toyota Silver 6544
#3    BMW    Red 4792
#
#[[3]]
#      V1     V2   V3
#1   Ford    Red 8041
#2 Toyota Silver 6544
#3    BMW    Red 4792
```

then after the do.call

```
#      V1     V2   V3
#1   Ford    Red 8041
#2 Toyota Silver 6544
#3    BMW    Red 4792
#4   Ford    Red 8041
#5 Toyota Silver 6544
#6    BMW    Red 4792
#7   Ford    Red 8041
#8 Toyota Silver 6544
#9    BMW    Red 4792
```

then we can change the column names, being unnecessarily explicit about the indeces

```
colnames(dataframe)[c(1,2,3)]<-c("car", "color", "price")
```

we can also add the year

```
dataframe$Year<-1 #all years are 1

#     car  color price Year
#1   Ford    Red  8041    1
#2 Toyota Silver  6544    1
#3    BMW    Red  4792    1
#4   Ford    Red  8041    1
#5 Toyota Silver  6544    1
#6    BMW    Red  4792    1
#7   Ford    Red  8041    1
#8 Toyota Silver  6544    1
#9    BMW    Red  4792    1
```

and here is a dput of the data after the lapply call

```
list(structure(list(V1 = c("Ford", "Toyota", "BMW"), V2 = c("Red", 
"Silver", "Red"), V3 = c(8041L, 6544L, 4792L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    V1 = c("Ford", "Toyota", "BMW"), V2 = c("Red", "Silver", 
    "Red"), V3 = c(8041L, 6544L, 4792L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    V1 = c("Ford", "Toyota", "BMW"), V2 = c("Red", "Silver", 
    "Red"), V3 = c(8041L, 6544L, 4792L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Comment: What does 'vector of names' mean exactly though? I have just checked the structure, it is telling me I only have 1 variable, when I should have 3. Is there a way of ammending the code I have above to separate it into 3 variables?
I tried "data = lapply(files,header=FALSE,sep=",",function(x) read.table(x))" but get the error "Error in FUN(c("abc.txt", "def.txt", "ghi.txt", "jkl.txt",  : 
  unused arguments (header = FALSE, sep = ",")"

Comment: I'm not sure about what exactly your data is, you'd need to post an example.  By vector of names, I mean this.  Take the case where you have a dataframe with columns A, B, and C.  You want to change the names of column B and C to be X and Y respecctively, then your vector of names would be c("X", "Y") and you would change the column names by colnames(dataframe)[c(2,3)]<-vectorOfNames

Comment: also that's not the correct way to call lapply for read.table.  You should do lapply(files, read.table, header=FALSE, sep=","), other arguments that are passed to the function you are applying are specified after the function

Comment: Hi, I realise now why I got the error - what should be 3 columns of data is contained within the one column. I am still very new to R, so I have no idea why this happened. Your code should work if I figure out how to separate the data into separate columns...

Comment: @perriebtee do each of your files have one column of data?

Comment: My files are txt files which I have worked with before and normally they are fine separately - but I have never combined them all before. Each file contains rows of 3 values separated by a comma
For example, 
Toyota,Red,8400
Ford,Silver,6540
BMW,Red,4792

Comment: @perriebtee if you could run dput(data) after you run lapply that would help.  If your data sets are very large create copies of each with only 10 or so rows and then run through the lapply

Comment: Hmmm...what should I be looking out for?

Comment: @perriebtee I don't exactly know, but I just made an example txt file and went through your code with my corrections, and everything worked fine, so the results of your read.table are probably not what you expect them to be

Comment: as for the dput suggestion, you would then post the result of the dput in your question, because it spits out a copy-paste-able data structure of what you're working with

Comment: So the data was in 3 separate columns for you? I must be missing something in my own so, like I said it normally works fine for me. Thankyou for all your help. One last question if you don't mind, R will recognise "df$Year<-values" to give a column titled 'Year' with the values as the name of each file. For example if file names are "Year2000", "Year2001", "Year2002" it will automatically add these in.

Comment: yes, but you'll need to match them up to the specific entries by replicating.  google "r recycling" to see what I'm talking about

Comment: I am just seeing your edit now - thankyou very much!